# How do I check if a Model name exists in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

What Django command(s) must I use to check if model `SomeModelName` exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django has an `django.apps` module with an `apps` class:

```
from django.apps import apps
```

this `apps` class has a `get_models()` function, that returns the `Model` classes (these do not include abstract models, and tables as a result of `ManyToManyField`s).

We can use `.__name__` to obtain the classname. So we can check if `SomeModelName` exists with:

```
from operator import attrgetter

'SomeModelName' in map(attrgetter('__name__'), apps.get_models())
```

Note that this will specify the name of the classes, and that in the different applications you have registered, several models can have the *same* name (but these are *not* the same model).

Comment: Or: `apps.get_model(my_app_label, model_name)`. Raises a `LookupError` if the model_name does not exist.

Comment: I get the error @CoffeeBasedLifeform mentions when I use Willem's code when I run `manage.py custom_command`. But when I run Willem's code in `manage.py shell` it returns `true` or `false` just fine...

Comment: @Username: well this is exactly what coffeeBasedLifeForm means: it raises an error if the model name does not exists.

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform: well there is a potential problem if we do not know what the `app_label` is.

Comment: `apps.app_configs` or `apps.get_app_configs()` could be used to get a list of installed apps.

Comment: My app name is "theme", with `models.py` being in the "theme" folder if that makes any difference...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Would I use your code to return a boolean or should I put it in a `try` block?

Comment: Just to clarify: are you looking for the model_name `ModelClass._meta.model_name` or the name of the ModelClass itself `ModelClass.__name__`? They are not the same: the former is always lower case.

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform The latter, the non-lowercase one.

Comment: In that case go with Willem's idea and expect a boolean.